# Moving cursor to the desired position that user clicked in java swing JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to know how in Java swing, it is possible to move the caret in the JTextArea to my desired position that I click.

If this is not possible then what could I do to make it possible?
(like IntelliJ virtual spaces).
and I want to do any time whether the text area is blank or not.

Comment: *move the cursor in the JTextArea to my desired position that I click.* This happens by default when you click on text.  *I want to do any time whether the text area is blank or not.* - There is no such thing as "virtual spaces". You need to pad your text area with spaces to fill the text area.

Comment: @camickr thank you. but I'm using the text area with scroll, so how can I fill it with space?

Comment: That is your challenge. I don't have an answer for that.